# ruby on rails installation on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

error on installation

**ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand**

wat should i do plz help as soon as possible

Comment: How far have you got? Is Ruby installed? Which version?  Are you using rvm/bundler?  Is rails installed? which version?  Full stacktrace would be good.  Are you following a guide, which one?  Are you using the apt-get package ruby/gems?  As you shouldnt...

Answer (score 2):

Try following this guide.  its very good

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I was installing Rails on Ubuntu but I was able to install zlib and then proceeded to installing Rails.

Here's what I did:

1. Download and installed zlib from source.

   wget http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz
   tar -xvzf zlib-1.2.7.tar.gz
   cd zlib-1.2.7/
   sudo ./configure && sudo make && sudo make install
2. "Register" zlib module before recompiling and reinstalling Ruby

   cd ruby-source-distro-path/ext/zlib

   sudo ruby extconf.rb

   sudo make && sudo make install